# Foreach inside foreach only showing one result

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database");
// Check connection 
   if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
 error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
 $query = "SELECT * FROM TT_posts WHERE post_status='publish' AND 
ping_status='open'";
 $result = $con->query($query);
 while($row1 = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
 foreach ($result as $row1){

$image = "SELECT * FROM TT_posts WHERE post_title='$row1[post_name]'";
 $result1 = $con->query($image);
 while($row2 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) 
 foreach ($result1 as $row2){
 echo "<img src='".$row2[guid]."'>";
 echo "<p>".$row1[post_title]."</p>";
 }}
 ?>
```

actually, below query returns 8 results.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM TT_posts WHERE post_status='publish' AND 
ping_status='open'";
```

When it executed the loop, it stops at the first result. I don't know what exactly stops the code.

Comment: Why are you doing a `foreach` within the `while`? `while($row2 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) { echo "<img src='".$row2[guid]."'>";}` should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've got your variable names mixed up.  Your first `while` assigns a row to `$row1`, then your `foreach` refers to `$result`, not `$row1`.  The variable `$row1` is actually being overwritten every time it loops around the `foreach`.

You don't actually need either `foreach`:

```
while ($row1 = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $image = "SELECT * FROM TT_posts WHERE post_title='$row1[post_name]'";
  $result1 = $con->query($image);
  while ($row2 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) { 
    echo "<img src='".$row2[guid]."'>";
    echo "<p>".$row1[post_title]."</p>";
  }
}
```

Comment: thats why in the foreach loop i have given then row2,result2 like wise variable names...

Comment: No, in the first while/foreach... In the while, $row1 is assigned the first row.  In the foreach, you're referring to the whole result set, not the row. You don't actually need the foreach at all.

Comment: Take out the foreach statements, making sure you put braces { } on the while statements as appropriate.

Comment: Code added to answer above.

Comment: it worked but getting only one image result, 8 title results.

Comment: Without seeing the contents of those tables it's difficult to comment.  Do you expect to see multiple images against each post?

Comment: yes, 8 images and 8 post titles . but actual result is 1 image , 8 post titles